# How to read the first image in folder using opencv (python)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, glob, imread

I am using the following code to read and compute difference between consecutive images in a folder:

```
def cal_for_frames(video_path):
    frames = glob(os.path.join(video_path, '*.jpg'))
    frames.sort()


    diff = []
    prev = cv2.imread(frames[0])
    prev = cv2.cvtColor(prev, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print(prev.dtype, prev.shape)
    for i, frame_curr in enumerate(frames):
        curr = cv2.imread(frame_curr)
        curr = cv2.cvtColor(curr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        print(curr.dtype, curr.shape)
        tmp_diff = compute_DIFF(prev, curr)
        diff.append(tmp_diff)
        prev = curr
    
    return diff
```

Now I want my `prev` to always be the first image in the folder (i.e., to be constant). What changes do I need to make to `prev = cv2.imread(frames[0])` to do this? where `frame000001` is the first image in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `for-loop`'s last line: `prev = curr` and `prev = cv2.imread(frames[0])`.

But you can speed up your `for-loop`. If `print` function is not crucial, then you can do:

```py
diff = [compute_DIFF(prev, cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(frame_curr), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)) for i, frame_curr in enumerate(frames)]
```

Code:

---

```py
def cal_for_frames(video_path):
    frames = glob(os.path.join(video_path, '*.jpg')).sort()
    prev = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(frames[0]), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print(prev.dtype, prev.shape)

    diff = [compute_DIFF(prev, cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(frame_curr), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)) for i, frame_curr in enumerate(frames)]

    return diff
```

Comment: Thanks! removing ```prev=curr``` did the trick. One more question, I am trying to save the images with ```"frame{%06d}.jpg".format(i)``` but I get a ```KeyError: '%06d'```. It works fine when when I use ```"frame{}.jpg".format(i)```, I'd like to know what I am doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: Using ```"frame{%06d}.jpg".format(i)``` worked in the past, don't know why it doesn't work now.

Comment: I got it to work. I changed ```"frame{%06d}.jpg".format(i)``` to ```"frame{:06d}.jpg".format(i)```. Thanks for your help.